# Confusion over a Haskell "Existential Wrapper"

Tags: haskell

From a Haskell file:

```
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

-- |Existential wrapper 
data Some :: (* -> Constraint) -> * where
  Some :: f a => { unSome :: a } -> Some f
```

I know that `Constraint` represents a kind distinct from `*` that can be used to categorize context types that appear to the left of a `=>`.

But in what sense is `Some` an existential wrapper? How could it be used as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strange GADT/record syntax that doesn't look like it should compile aside, we can understand what is going on here by setting `f ~ Eq`:

```
Some :: Eq a => a -> Some Eq
```

So, given an `Eq`uatable thing, we get `Some Eq`uatable thing out of it. Let's apply this to `'a' :: Char` and see what happens:

```
(Some :: Eq Char => Char -> Some Eq) ('a' :: Char) :: Some Eq
```

As you can see, we have "forgotten" the exact type of the value, but "remembered" that it is `Eq`uatable.

The GADT you provide is simply a generalization of this from `Eq` to anything with kind `* -> Constraint`:

```
(Eq :: * -> Constraint) (Char :: *) :: Constraint
(f :: * -> Constraint) (a :: *) :: Constraint
```

As for why it is called "existential", the GADT hides an implicit `forall` in the constructor declaration:

```
Some :: forall a. f a => { unSome :: a } -> Some f
```

Once you pattern match on `Some f`, you get a value of type `f a => a`, where `a` can't escape its scope for technical reasons. (Which is called [skolem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719435/what-are-skolems)) You can use a CPS combinator like this to work with it:

```
ambiguously :: (forall s. f s => s -> r) -> Some f -> r
ambiguously f (Some s) = f s
```

Now you have `ambiguously show :: Some Show -> String`, which shows `Some Show`able thing. It is called "ambiguously" because it is ambiguous in which actual type it is using (ie it works for `ambiguously show $ Some 'a'` and `ambiguously show $ Some "asdf"`)

We can't do

```
disambiguate :: f a => Some f -> a
disambiguate (Some a) = a
```

because of the aforementioned skolem restriction.

[My (unpublished) library](https://github.com/Lazersmoke/ghost-buster/blob/master/src/Data/SuchThat.hs#L22) related to this, with an even more general kind.

Comment: TIL that [GADT/record syntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/gadt.html) is completely valid