# Haskell GADT 'Show'- instance type-variable deduction

Tags: haskell, type-inference, gadt, type-variables

This code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Expr a where
    Val :: Num a => a -> Expr a
    Eq :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (Val x) = x
eval (Eq x y) = (eval x) == (eval y)

instance Show a => Show (Expr a) where
    show (Val x) = "Val " ++ (show x)
    show (Eq x y) = "Eq (" ++ (show y) ++ ") (" ++ (show x) ++ ")"
```

fails to compile with the following error message:

```
Test.hs:13:32: error:
    * Could not deduce (Show a1) arising from a use of `show'
      from the context: Show a
        bound by the instance declaration at test.hs:11:10-32
      or from: (a ~ Bool, Eq a1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Eq :: forall a. Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
                 in an equation for `show'
        at test.hs:13:11-16
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a1) to the context of the data constructor `Eq'
    * In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(show y)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely
        `(show y) ++ ") (" ++ (show x) ++ ")"'
      In the expression: "Eq (" ++ (show y) ++ ") (" ++ (show x) ++ ")" Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Commenting out the last line fixes the issue and inspecting the type of `Expr` in GHCi reveals, that, instead of inferring `Eq` to be of type `Eq a => (Expr a) -> (Expr a) -> Expr Bool`, GHC actually infers it to be `Eq a1 => (Expr a1) -> (Expr a1) -> Expr Bool` for
`data Expr a where ...`. This explains the error message, since `instance Show a => Show (Expr a) where ...` won't enforce `a1` to be an instance of `Show`.

However I do *not* understand, *why* GHC chooses to do so. If I had to make a guess, I'd say it has something to do with `Eq` returning a value, that doesn't depend on `a` at all and thus GHC "forgetting" about `a`, once `Eq` returns a `Expr Bool`. Is this - at least sort of - what is happening here?

Also, is there a clean solution to this? I tried several things, including trying to "force" the desired type via `InstanceSigs` and `ScopedTypeVariables` doing something like this:

```
instance Show a => Show (Expr a) where
    show :: forall a. Eq a => Expr a -> String
    show (Eq x y) = "Eq (" ++ (show (x :: Expr a)) ++ ") (" ++ (show (y :: Expr a)) ++ ")"
    ...
```

, but with no success. And since I'm still a Haskell novice, I'm not even sure, if this could somehow work anyways, due to my initial guess why GHC doesn't infer the "correct"/desired type in the first place.

EDIT:

Ok, so I decided to add a function

```
extract (Eq x _) = x
```

to the file (without a type signature), just to see, what return type it  would have. GHC again refused to compile, but this time, the error message contained some information about skolem type variables. A quick search yielded [this question](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CcwpCsPRWIgJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719435/what-are-skolems+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de), which (I think?) formalizes, what I believe the issue to be: Once `Eq :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool` returns a `Expr Bool`, `a` goes "out of scope". Now we don't have any information left about `a`, so `extract` would have to have the signature `exists a. Expr Bool -> a`, since `forall a. Expr Bool -> a` won't be true for every `a`. But because GHC doesn't support `exists`, type-checking fails.

Comment: The easiest solution is to change signature of Eq from `Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool`, which allows `a` in this context to be whichever numeric type (which may or may not be instance of class show), to `(Eq a, Show a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool` which will allow to construct eq only expression only when comparing expressions of showable type.

Comment: Thank you, this works; however a solution without this additional requirement in the type constructor would be interesting as well

Comment: With the original type there is no good solution. There is just too little you can do with an existential type. Another way is to restrict `Val` to a fixed type (or to have multiple `Val`-like constructors representing a finite set of types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is *not* requiring a `Show a` superconstraint.

```
instance Show (Expr a) where
  showsPrec p (Eq x y) = showParen (p>9)
       $ ("Eq "++) . showsPrec 10 x . (' ':) . showsPrec 10 y
```

Of course this somewhat kicks the stone down the road, because now you can *not* write

```
  showsPrec p (Val x) = showParen (p>9) $ ("Val "++) . showsPrec 10 x
```

anymore – now the leaf-value is not `Show` constrained. But here you can hack your way around this by making the `Num` constraint a bit stronger:

```
data Expr a where
    Val :: RealFrac a => a -> Expr a
    Eq :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
instance Show (Expr a) where
  showsPrec p (Val x) = showParen (p>9) $ ("Val "++)
          . showsPrec 10 (realToFrac x :: Double)
```

Well, that is a big hack, and at that point you might as well use simply

```
data Expr a where
    Val :: Double -> Expr Double
    Eq :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

(or whatever other single type best fits your number requirements). That's not a good solution.

To retain the ability to store numbers of *any* type in `Expr` leaves, yet be able to constrain them to `Show` if desired, you need to be *polymorphic on the constraint*.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data Expr (c :: * -> Constraint) a where
    Val :: (Num a, c a) => a -> Expr a
    Eq :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

Then you can do

```
instance Show (Expr Show a) where
  showsPrec p (Val x) = showParen (p>9) $ ("Val "++) . showsPrec 10 x
  showsPrec p (Eq x y) = showParen (p>9)
       $ ("Eq "++) . showsPrec 10 x . (' ':) . showsPrec 10 y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it seems, it indeed would be easiest, to just use concrete types. However your second solution is really interesting, too. I never heard of `-XConstraintKinds` before, so I will do some testing with that - experimenting with Haskell extensions truly feels like going down the rabbit hole sometimes!

Comment: Right now I only have a (minor) - unrelated to the original - question: The (latest) GHC User's Guide states: "[-XConstraintKinds] Allow types of kind Constraint to be used in contexts.", however I was under the impression, that contexts were something before "=>". But in your example, you used `Constraint` in the kind signature. Is that also considered a context or did they just use the term a bit more leniently?

Comment: I've used “`Constraint`” in the kind signature, but _the thing of kind `Constraint`_ is `c` and that's indeed used in the _context_ of the `Val` constructor.

Comment: I guess using `data Expr (c :: * -> Constraint) a where` leads to using a lot of `unsafeCoerce` to avoid traversing the whole expression just to lift an `Expr c` into an `Expr d` whenever `d a` entails `c a` for all a. :/

Comment: @gallais yes, this is totally awkward when you want to change leaf-constraints of a given tree somehow. My suggestion assumes that this will never be necessary...

Comment: On second thought: `unsafeCoerce` may not even work because of the mismatch between the representations of the set of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I will only explain this point.

> However I do not understand, why GHC chooses to do so.

The issue is, one can write a custom type with a `Num` and `Eq` instance, but no `Show` one.

```
newtype T = T Int deriving (Num, Eq) -- no Show, on purpose!
```

Then, this type checks:

```
e1 :: Expr T
e1 = Val (T 42)
```

as does this:

```
e2 :: Expr Bool
e2 = Eq e1 e1
```

However, it should be clear that `e1` and `e2` can not be `show`ed. To print these, we would need `Show T`, which is missing.

Further, the constraint

```
instance Show a => Show (Expr a) where
      -- ^^^^^^
```

is useless here, since we do have `Show Bool`, but this is not enough to print `e2 :: Expr Bool`.

This is the problem of existential types: you get what you pay for. When we construct `e2 = Eq e1 e2` we only have to "pay" the constraint `Eq T`. Hence, when we pattern match `Eq a b` we only get `Eq t` back (where `t` is a suitable type variable). We do not get to know whether `Show t` holds. Indeed, even if we did remember `t ~ T`, we would still lack the required `Show T` instance.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, however just to clarify: The _actual_ issue is, that we don't remember, that `t ~ T`, right? That's why we can only do something like `show (Eq x y) = show (x == y)`.
Because in my example, if we remembered `t ~ a`, due to the `Show a` constraint, we then should be able to deduce `Show t`.

Comment: @BenjaminRickels No, as I try to explain above, that is not sufficient in general. In your example, yes, that would suffice. However, since it is possible that someone chooses a `T` without a `Show` instance, GHC can not accept that code :-( You need to make `Eq x y` to require `Eq a` where `x,y::a`, otherwise you can craft expressions that can not be showed.

Comment: @BenjaminRickels No. The actual issue is your instance says `Show a => Show (Expr a)`. But `a` in `Expr a` is the type of the overall expression, which for `Eq` is always `Bool`. That has no connection to the type of the two arguments to `Eq`! Because presumably you want to be able to represent an equality test of two integer-expressions, which is a Boolean expression overall; the `a` in the arguments does not have to be the same type as the `a` in the overall expression. So by this design, you **cannot** constrain the arguments by putting constraints on the overall type.

Comment: @chi and @Ben, thanks for helping me out! I think I now understand; I was constantly wondering about what if GHC could theoretically retain information about which types were originally used, to construct a `Expr Bool` with the `Eq` constructor. I thought then it should surely be possible to correlate those with `Show a` upon deconstructing `Eq`. But it didn't really occur to me, that the `a` in this case actually refers to `Bool`. In hindsight the initial error message makes a lot more sense now as well!